Passive voice with sense verbs

I saw him run- I saw the entire action

Can  I use the same structure in passive?
He was seen run not running?

He was seen to run is possible, though fairly formal. By contrast, *He was seen run is not grammatically possible in English.

'I saw him run' does not automatically mean I saw the whole action.

OP's query is on conversion from Active to Passive voice:

I saw him run- I saw the entire action.
Can I use the same structure in passive?

Consider the following Active voice sentence:
1. "I saw him run to the market"
means (as suggested by OP) I saw the entire action from start to finish.
If you convert it to passive using the Present Participle form  "running".
2. "He was seen  running to the market".
It implies ongoing action. He was already running when seen.
If you use the "to infinitive" instead of the bare infinitive.
3. "He was seen to run to the market".
He was seen at the start. It doesn't imply complete action from start to finish.
This can be seen as a limitation of converting active voice to passive voice.
So if you wish to maintain the meaning of the original active voice sentence, you have to add a phrase:.
He was seen running all the way to the market.

You can say the same sentence in both active and passive forms. But you need to learn the grammatical patterns for each case; they are not exactly the same.


I saw him run to the bus stop.
I saw him running to the bus stop.


I have added both of these forms because they are both valid, but they don't mean the same thing. And that has consequences for the passive form. Sentence #1 means that I saw the whole run, right through to the moment when he arrived at the bus stop. Sentence #2 means that when I saw him, he was running towards the bus stop; he may or may not have reached it while I was still watching.
The passive forms of those sentences are:


He was seen to run to the bus stop by me.
He was seen running to the bus stop by me.


These two passive sentences have the same parallel meanings: In sentence #3 I saw the whole run; in sentence #4 I saw him at a particular moment, and at that moment he was running.
Note that sentences #2 and #4 have the same form of the verb (running, the gerund form). But to go from sentence #1 to sentence #3 you need to change the verb form. The passive requires the infinitive, to run.
Note also that the passive forms are more complex than the active forms. The expression seen...by me is split up because of the intervening clause running to the bus stop. And you can't easily fix this by changing the word order. If I write...


He was seen by me running to the bus stop.


...we now have the classic ambiguity question: Who was running? Him or me?
So when you use the passive form you need to be careful in your wording. Active is often better.

I would argue that "I saw him run to market" could mean that you saw him run from a particular spot to market, NOT necessarily from the point where he started his run. So he might well have started his run from home and you might well have seen him run from the library (further along the street) to market.
